# Is using an uninitialized unsigned type object Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unsigned-integer

I know that using (accessing the value) an uninitialized non-static and non-global object of type built-in integral type is Undefined behavior.

```
int x; // x is defined inside a function scope for example main
++x;// UB

signed char c = 127; // max positive value for char on my machine

c++; // UB overflowing a signed char.
```

- Until here it is OK but what about unsigned types?

  ```
     unsigned char uc = 255; // ok
     uc++; // ok c now has the value 0
  ```

It is OK here because overflowing an unsigned will discard the bits outside the range.

- So as long as any value assigned to an unsigned is it harmless to do this:

  ```
  unsigned int x; // local non-static uninitialized

  std::cout << x << '\n';// is it UB or OK?
  ```
- AS you can see that any (indeterminate) value set to an unsigned doesn't cause a UB so is it wrong to do so?
- I don't matter what value in `x` but I think it doesn't cause any harm.
- If it is OK then I guess it looks like a random value can be generated by the compiler from using an uninitialized unsigned non-static non-global object.

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question. "_I know that using (accessing the value) an uninitialized non-static and non-global object of type built-in integral type is Undefined behavior._" "_but what about unsigned types?_" Unsigned types are also built-in integral types, are they not?

Comment: Unsigned integers don't overflow for your information

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Could you add as answer?

Comment: "*so is it wrong to do so?*" Well that depends on your definition of "wrong." Are you trying to show the user a "random" value every time they run the program? Then yes, this is wrong, the compiler may initialize that to 0 for you depending on your compiler. Or it may be the *same* "junk" value every time. Please define "wrong" in this context.

Comment: I don't understand why you think unsigned overflow behaviour tells us anything about uninitialized indeterminate values. And I really don't understand what you think "causing a UB" would look like - did you expect a crash or diagnostic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is using an uninitialized unsigned type object Undefined Behavior?

Yes.

> but I think it doesn't cause any harm.

You might be right.  But since it's UB you might also be wrong.  ***You can never be sure***.

One sneaky thing compilers do is detect your Undefined Behavior and "optimize" your program by outright removing code paths that reach this UB.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/4f9qbj) (program compiles, but does nothing)

Comment: One can be sure of program behaviors on implementations that either expressly document the behaviors, or document how they process actions in terms of the target platform, and which, as a form of "conforming language extension", process cases where the Standard and such documentation together would describe a behavior, but other parts of the Standard that would classify it as UB, in a way that consistent with the described behavior without regard for whether the Standard would require them to do so.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) :

> Use of an indeterminate value obtained by default-initializing a non-class variable of any type is undefined behavior

An object with an indeterminate value is distinct from an object whose value you don't know. Using an indeterminate value is Undefined Behavior (with a few exceptions, see the link above) even if every possible value the object could have would have defined behavior.

It is an error to assume that an object with indeterminate value has any one of its possible values. The reason `++x` is Undefined Behavior is not because it might already have the maximum value and overflow. It is Undefined Behavior simply because `x` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

If uninitialized objects were required to behave as though they were initialized with some unspecified bit pattern, that would impede some useful optimizations and diagnostics.  While there are times when it may be useful for programs to be able to perform some operations with uninitialized objects (e.g. if code initializes a variable subset of the objects in a group, and wants to copy all of the initialized ones, blindly copying all of the objects may be faster than trying to selectively copy only the initialized ones or having initialize the objects whose values affect program execution), there are other times when the diagnostics or optimizations would be more helpful.  Because the authors of the Standard can't possibly know in every case whether it would be most useful to have implementations treat uninitialized values as though initialized with unspecified bit patterns, as causing a trap when read, or behaving in some other ways that might facilitate optimization, they allow implementations to process such situations in whatever manner would be most useful to their customers.

Consider, for example:

```
struct thing { uint32_t count; uint16_t dat[126]; };
struct thing x,y,z;

void test(void)
{
  struct thing temp;
  temp.count = readInteger();
  for (int i=0; i<temp.count; i++)
    temp.dat[i] = readInteger;
  x = temp;
  y = temp;
  z = y;
}
```

Depending upon the code's intended purpose, there are at least five ways it might be useful to have implementations process it:

1. Treat `temp` as though unwritten parts were initialized with arbitrary bit patterns, which would then be copied into `x`, `y`, and `z` (meaning both structures would be guaranteed to hold matching unspecified data).
2. Trap on the attempt to copy `temp` without fully initializing its contents, since code which copies uninitialized data can pose a security risk if the execution context would have access to confidential data.
3. Treat every read of an uninitialized part of an automatic object as though it might yield an independent unspecified value, thus allowing a compiler to leave the corresponding parts of `x` and `y` holding any convenient values (including whatever they happened to hold before the function call), but treat a store of an indeterminate value to a static-duration or heap-duration object as though it writes an unspecified bit pattern (so unwritten parts of `y` and `z` would be guaranteed to match each other, even though they might not match `x`).
4. Treat every read of an indeterminate value as yielding a "contagious" indeterminate value, thus allowing a compiler to leave the corresponding parts of `x`, `y`, and `z` holding any convenient values, with no guarantee that any of them match.
5. Use the fact that code would invoke UB if `temp.count` weren't equal to 126 to optimize calling code based upon the fact that it "will" always equal 126.

Because none of the above behaviors would be most useful in every case, the Standard allows compilers to select among them in whatever fashion would be most useful to their customers.